# Packaging an Electron app for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, electron

I cannot get an electron app I created installed on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian. I've used electron-packager to create the package, and then create a debian installer. Threw the installer on a thumb drive and onto the Raspberry Pi and hit install but only received this error popup: "A package could not be found that allows the action to complete. More information is available in the detailed report."

The Raspberry Pi is running arm7l according to the cpuinfo. The electron app was packaged for arm7l as well (name of the file even ends in it). I'm guessing you all will need plenty more background - just not sure what - so feel free to ask and I'll try to edit as quick as I can :)

Commands I used to package it and make installer:

```
"package-linux": "electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=armv7l --icon=assets/icons/png/1024x1024.png --prune=true --out=release-builds",

"create-debian-installer": "electron-installer-debian --src /Users/myuser/Documents/Signage/release-builds/signage-linux-armv7l --arch armv7l --config debian.json"
```

**EDIT**: I've run

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armv7l
```

which got me further than before. But I get the following error, when I try the following command:

```
udo dpkg --install /home/pi/Desktop/signage_0.1.0_armv7l.deb(Reading database ... 154822 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../signage_0.1.0_armv7l.deb ...
Unpacking signage:armv7l (0.1.0) over (0.1.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of signage:armv7l:
 signage:armv7l depends on libgtk-3-0.
 signage:armv7l depends on libnotify4.
 signage:armv7l depends on libnss3.
 signage:armv7l depends on libxss1.
 signage:armv7l depends on libxtst6.
 signage:armv7l depends on libatspi2.0-0.
 signage:armv7l depends on libuuid1.

dpkg: error processing package signage:armv7l (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.31.4-3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.62) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 signage:armv7l
```

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg` can't install your package because it depends on others, listed under `... depends on ...`, namely those:

> signage:armv7l depends on libgtk-3-0.
>    signage:armv7l depends on libnotify4.
>    signage:armv7l depends on libnss3.
>    signage:armv7l depends on libxss1.
>    signage:armv7l depends on libxtst6.
>    signage:armv7l depends on libatspi2.0-0.
>    signage:armv7l depends on libuuid1.

Because `dpkg` does not do dependency resolution, you will need to install them first manually. The following command will do the trick:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-0 libnotify4 libnss3 libxss1 libxtst6 libatspi2.0-0 libuuid1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are building an electron app for Raspberry with a Debian OS, first install `electron-packager` and also `electron-installer-debian`.

Then run:

1. `electron-packager . appname --platform linux --arch x64 --out out/`
2. `electron-installer-debian --src out/appname-linux-x64/ --dest out/installers/ --arch armhf`

Notice the flag `--arch armhf` in the second command. This will prevent the error mentioned in the question. Once you have the .deb file, you can install it in Debian `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb`